# ADO.NET connect results in Instance Failure

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

When I try to establish a connection to SQL Server using ADO.NET, it shows errors.

This is the code I use:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=abdul;uid=sa;pwd=sqlserver");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

con.Open();

String str="select * from emp where empname='Abdul'";
cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (dr == null || !dr.HasRows)
{
   MessageBox.Show("No Records found");
}
else
{
   while (dr.Read())
   {
      textBox1.Text = dr[0].ToString();
      textBox2.Text = dr[1].ToString();
   }
}
```

When I am running the project it shows the following error:

> Instance failure.

What do I have to do?

Comment: Can you copy the error StackTrace please?

Comment: @Alberto Leon: Following is the error Stack Trace    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String  It's not enough to put the all

Comment: Why don't you use ConnectionStringBuilder for this:SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=abdul;uid=sa;pwd=sqlserver");?

Comment: you should also wrap connection and data readers in using(){} blocks. Regarding to the question: have you checked that the connection is OK?

Comment: @Hohhi: Can you tell me how to use the ConnectionStringBuilder

Comment: @Hohhi: Sorry i am new to SqlServer, can you tell me how to check the connection.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx try this for reading about ConnectionStringBuilders

Comment: try to add a new Data Source in DataSources tool window in Visual Studio, there will be a button test connection in a wizard

Comment: @Hohhi: Thank you very much,i rectified the error, as i done by your words, i rectified it. Thank you very much..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are marking the connection string with @ to make it a literal you should only use one backslash in the data source

> DataSource=.\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: I tried that also, when i trying this it shows the following error: Login failed for user 'sa'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

Comment: Thank You very much, really the problem is with Connection String only, i rectified that by using DataSource. Really thank you...

Comment: Your problem is only with credentials, @PaulB is right about the @